# A moving point has its distance from (1,3) always one-third of its distance from (8,2). Find the equation of its Locus.

Tags: analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, locus

A moving point has its distance from (1,3) always one-third of its distance from (8,2).
Find the equation of its Locus.

My equation displays a circle formed by the loci, I don't know if it's right.  Please help me find the equation, Thank you in advance to those that can answer.

Comment: Then what is the equation of the circle you have found?

Comment: I got two different equations of its locus, both of which does not meet the condition on the above problem.

the first one is ====>8/9x^2 -149/9x +8/9y^2 - 14/3y+602/9=0
the second one is
===> -1/3x^2 +38/3x + 106/3 - 1/3y^2 +10/3y=0

Comment: We get $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-3)^2}=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{(x-8)^2+(y-2)^2}$. Square both sides, multiply through by $9$, simplify.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}3^2\left[(x-1)^2+(y-3)^2\right] =& (x-8)^2 + (y-2)^2\\
9\left(x^2-2x+y^2-6y+10\right) =& x^2-16x+y^2-4x+68\\
8x^2-2x+8y^2-50y+22 =& 0\\
x^2-\frac14x+y^2-\frac{25}4y+\frac{11}4=&0\\
\left(x-\frac{1}{8}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{25}8\right)^2=&\frac{225}{32}\\
\left(x-\frac{1}{8}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{25}8\right)^2=&\left(\frac{15\sqrt2}{8}\right)^2
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much peter, just to check, I can find a value and test it with the condition by using distance formula right?

Comment: Peter, last question, I don't quite get the last two lines to your solution, can you explain how for those two last lines?

Comment: The fourth line to the fifth line is completing square, which is to convert 
$$x^2+bx = x^2+2\cdot\frac b2x+\left(\frac{b}2\right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4}=\left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4}.$$
From the fourth line, complete square once with variable $x$ and once with $y$, then move all constants to the right hand side. This is to make the quadratic equation to the form $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2.$$

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you Peter, I get it now, I've been finalizing answers not in that form, no wonder I was told to fix my answers a couple of times, uhmm, if it's not much trouble, can you help me how to plot this.  I'm a little off when it came to plotting, although the graphing calculator is showing the correct plots.

Comment: You can read the coordinates of centre and the radius from the equation of circle, if you convert the equation to $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ form. Use a pair of compasses to plot.